# Как загружать в один div несколько блоков

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Привет. 
Имеется div, в который должен загружать другие div'ы из нескольких страниц.
Сейчас у меня такой код:

```
<div id="get_message">Загрузка...</div> //Загружаю сюда
```

Скрипт:

```
$('#get_message').load('/blog/1 #Allmessages div:first');
```

Как видно, загружаю из страницы /blog/1 - первый div в блоке **#Allmessages**. - это понятно, но теперь нужно, загрузить из другой страницы в тот же div (#get_message)  еще другие div'ы.

Вот неправильный вариант, чтобы вы поняли о чем я:

```
$('#get_message').load('/blog/1 #Allmessages div:first');
$('#get_message').load('/blog/2 #Allmessages div:first');
$('#get_message').load('/blog/3 #Allmessages div:first');
$('#get_message').load('/blog/4 #Allmessages div:first');
//и, загружаю все сюда:
<div id="get_message">Загрузка...</div> //Загружаю сюда
```

Как правильнее организовать это? 
Спасибо, за внимание!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get("/blog/1/", function(data){
        $(data).find("#Allmessages div:first").appendTo("#get_message");
})
```

Comment: Разве это отличается от моего кода?   и для каждой страницы нужно прописать отдельно сколько строк?
Спасибо.

Comment: * вы используете синтаксис не $.get(), а $.ajax()
* dataType: "json" - не уместно
* data.find() - ничего не найдет

Comment: @Deonis, и действительно.

Comment: @Deonis, извините, поправил, кофе исправило поток мыслей)

Comment: @dekameron, Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 1, i <= 5, i++) {
  $('#get_message').load('/blog/' + i + '#Allmessages div:first');
}
```

Comment: 0_o  это что?

Comment: это цикл for который перебирает числа от 1 до 5(или до скольки надо вам) и подставляет их в строку запроса!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1, i <= 5, i++) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/blog/" + i + "/",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $('body').find("#Allmessages div:first").appendTo("#get_message");
    }
});
}
```

Может совместить посты двух предыдущих авторов? Не ручаюсь, что правильно.